# Canceling request of nuxt fetch hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuex

Since Nuxt's fetch hooks cannot run in parallel, I needed a way to cancel requests done in fetch hook when navigating to some other route so users don't have to wait for the first fetch to complete when landed on the homepage navigated to some other. So I found this approach: [How to cancel all Axios requests on route change](https://blog.andrewjamesbibby.com/2019/08/01/cancel-all-pending-axios-requests-in-vue-spa-on-router-change/)

So I've created these plugin files for Next:

router.js

```
export default ({ app, store }) => {
  // Every time the route changes (fired on initialization too)
  app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('cancel/cancel_pending_requests')
    next()
  })
}
```

axios.js

```
export default function ({ $axios, redirect, store }) {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    const source = $axios.CancelToken.source()

    config.cancelToken = source.token
    store.commit('cancel/ADD_CANCEL_TOKEN', source)
    return config
  }, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })
}
```

and a small vuex store for the cancel tokens:

```
export const state = () => ({
  cancelTokens: []
})

export const mutations = {
  ADD_CANCEL_TOKEN (state, token) {
    state.cancelTokens.push(token)
  },
  CLEAR_CANCEL_TOKENS (state) {
    state.cancelTokens = []
  }
}

export const actions = {
  cancel_pending_requests ({ state, commit }) {
    state.cancelTokens.forEach((request, i) => {
      if (request.cancel) {
        request.cancel('Request canceled')
      }
    })
    commit('CLEAR_CANCEL_TOKENS')
  }
}
```

Now this approach works fine and I can see requests get canceled with 499 on route change, however, it is flooding my devtools console with "Error in fetch()" error. Is there some preferred/better way to do this?

Example of fetch hook here:

```
async fetch () {
  await this.$store.dispatch('runs/getRunsOverview')
}
```

Example of dispatched action:

```
export const actions = {
  async getRunsOverview ({ commit }) {
    const data = await this.$axios.$get('api/frontend/runs')
    commit('SET_RUNS', data)
  }
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using fetch here with `fetchOnServer` set to `False` to display some loading placeholder to users.

The main problem is the flooded console with error, but I can also see that it also enters the `$fetchState.error` branch in my template, which displays div with "Something went wrong" text before route switches.

Edit 2:
Looked closer where this error comes from and it's mixin file `fetch.client.js` in `.nuxt/mixins` directory. Pasting the fetch function code below:

```
async function $_fetch() {
  this.$nuxt.nbFetching++
  this.$fetchState.pending = true
  this.$fetchState.error = null
  this._hydrated = false
  let error = null
  const startTime = Date.now()

  try {
    await this.$options.fetch.call(this)
  } catch (err) {
    if (process.dev) {
      console.error('Error in fetch():', err)
    }
    error = normalizeError(err)
  }

  const delayLeft = this._fetchDelay - (Date.now() - startTime)
  if (delayLeft > 0) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delayLeft))
  }

  this.$fetchState.error = error
  this.$fetchState.pending = false
  this.$fetchState.timestamp = Date.now()

  this.$nextTick(() => this.$nuxt.nbFetching--)
}
```

Have also tried to have everything using async/await as @kissu suggested in comments but with no luck :/

Comment: Where is the error coming from in your code? Is it blocking something or is it the fact that the console is spammed? Good question and nice code btw!

Comment: Hi @kissu i forgot to mention that i'm using fetch hook with fetchOnServer set to false so i can display some loading placeholder since the requests are pretty long. And i can also see that it enters $fetchState.error for a moment. So i'd like to mitigate both the flooded console and also entering this $fetchState.error branch of my code which is just  a div with "Something went wrong" text

Comment: Feel free to add this to your initial question by editing it. Also, did you tried using `await store.dispatch('cancel/cancel_pending_requests')` rather than `store.commit` in your `axios.js` file? Same for `router.js`? You probably should keep everything async and await it here. Mutations are sync so it's maybe coming from this. I mean, it could also be wished to have it sync here...but the error may come from the axios config file IMO.

Comment: Updated the queston a bit and tried to use async/await in axios.js and router.js plugin files but still getting the same error in console :/

Comment: Which line exactly is the error coming from?

Comment: It's line 75 in the whole file and in the pasted function above it's this line `console.error('Error in fetch():', err)` so it is apparent that it goes to console ony in dev mode, not really sure what it does when in production mode tho.

Comment: I had a situation where I did not want a search query to complete if a user clicked on a different option. The way I am handling it is wrapping the requests in a plugin, so you can use `this.$myRequest()`, then in that plugin, injecting the cancellation function when it's generated. So I can call `this.$cancelMyRequest` before `this.$myRequest`. I don't know if this is a bad way to do it, but it works and I think the only adaptation for this use case would be to inject a function that executes an array of functions, rather than the last cancellation function, then clear the array.